# run glassfish on home web server

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, webserver

This is the first time I set up a home web server and I use Glassfish for this.

- I already did port forwarding to the computer in router I use as server.
- I changed the port of glassfish( using netbean ) to 80
- I changed address in network listener to the current ip address (192.168.1.xxx) that router forwards to

I don't know what I need to do next. what I am trying to do is that when I type router ip address into browser, it will be able to see my welcome page. However, what I've got so far is connection time out error.

My question is how can I config (my machine, glassfish server) to make it possible to access to glassfish server.

Comment: Read read read and read some more. Nobody can help you with only an "it doesn't work". Nobody here has access to your server, your computer or your network. The only thing I can offer is a common mistake: a local firewall of the OS is blocking traffic maybe.

Comment: thank you, I watched couple tutorial videos so far and haven't got any solutions yet

Comment: Check that you can see the web server using the server's local address first. When port forwarding in order to see  the server you need to be outside your network and point at the routers wan address not its address on your local network. This is typically the address given to you by your ISP. Have a friend test it or use your phone so you are outside the network.

Comment: thank you @WillShackleford for reply,I tried to turn off my firewall and it works. Now what I try to figure out is to let my firewall on and let it allow the incoming connection.